# Is there software for comparing fonts side-by-side?

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, typefaces

Is there an application (or website) that allows you to select multiple fonts from a list and displays Lorem ipsum side-by-side for test purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to web sites, most font management applications have a feature to allow you to browse fonts in different manners.

I happen to use FontAgentProX. It has a "font compare" tab that allows you to highlight fonts (active or not) and see them side by side:

[image]

I'm sure Suitcase, FontExplorer, et. al. have similar features.

Answer (score 1):

If these are web fonts that are hosted you want to compare you could use a service like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) and in the CSS `@font-face src:(http://foobar.com/thisfont.woff);` you can add the fonts you want to compare against.

To learn how to use Adobe's Typekit you can reference "[Using Typekit on your blog](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/topics/2093-using-typekit-on-your-blog/articles)".

To use a Google Font:

[image]

There is a button called "Quick-use" when clicked will bring up after you scroll down:

[image]

---

If you are looking for a local solution locally I would use [Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/suitcase-fusion/) but at work we use [Universal Type Client](http://www.extensis.com/universal-type-server/) which allows is made by Extensis.  It even allows a compare feature to the nearest similarity of font you have if that is what you're looking for.